# Java Date format conversation Current time n date

Tags: java, android, date

What is the format of this date ?

```
"Sun Jan 26 19:23:10 +0000 2014"
```

I want to save current time in this format.

Comment: Read the `SimpleDateFormat` javadoc.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Search "java date format" on StackOverflow to find this question asked and answered many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android/Java date is really saved as a Calendar/long object (underlying is long milliseconds since the origin, Jan 1970). You can parse from or print to any format using SimpleDateFormat class.

That format, I believe, is:   "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"

assuming that +0000 is timezone and not milliseconds.